# How do you sync data between two browser tabs in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I am currently stuck in a situation where I have 3 different components and one of them is shared between the 2 two components and if I update shared component from any of the two components I want them to get updated on both of them is there a way to to do?

**ist-component**

```
       import {Component,bind,CORE_DIRECTIVES,OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {MainComponent} from 'src/MainComponent';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives:[MainComponent],
    template: `<h1>AppComponent {{onMain}}</h1>
    <div *ngIf="onMain == false">
       Hello
      <br> __________________________________<br>
    </div>
     <app-share></app-share>


    })

export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {}
```

**2nd-component**

```
          import {Component,bind,CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/core';
    import {SharedService} from 'src/shared.service';
    @Component({
        selector: 'sec-app',

        template: `<app-share></app-share>
                  <button (click)='changeCount()'></button>
`
    })

    export class SecondComponent {



        constructor(ss: SharedService) {
          this.ss = ss;
        }

        changeCount() {
          //want to change the count of shared component and also want a sync in first componen
        }
    }
```

**shared-component**

```
      import {Component,bind,CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-share',

    template: `{{count}}`
})

export class ShareComponent {

   count:any;
```

}

Now both the components are on loaded on different routes i.e browser with two tabs one tab has the first component and the second tab has the second component , so now i want a sync between the two components if i update the second component it must reflect on the first one

Comment: what do u mean shared? what is is parent-child relationship between them?

Comment: Share the code you have tried so far?

Comment: i updated my question with code you can see now

Comment: I guess question has to be `How do you sync data between two browser tabs in angular2?`

Answer (score -1):

Using "shared component" from the other two components will only share the code, not the data. I.e. two instantiations of "shared component" will be created, each with its own set of variables. Therefore updates to the data in one component will not be reflected in the other. This is by design.

If you need to share data between *any* two components you need to use Observables. You need to create a service that will own the shared data by declaring an Observable. All other components that need access to that shared data must subscribe to the observable within the service.

Comment: i have tried this solution but it will not share data if we are on two different tabs of  a browser , want to send data from one tab to the second tab

Comment: Well, you didn't mention the "two browser tabs" requirement in your original question. As you guessed, that changes the answer quite significantly.

Opening in mutiple tabs effectively runs separate copies of your application, one in each tab. The normal way to share data between separate copies of an application is through a third party data store, such as a cookie or a database.

Your app writes the "shared data" into a database or cookie then your app also reads from it. However you will have to manage the reading and writing yourself via some back end code, perhaps in an API layer.